# Pagination works locally, but not on the remote host

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

The pagination of the posts in my WordPress site works great in the development environment, but it doesn't work on the remote host.

Dividing the total number of posts into pages works, but the <kbd>next</kbd> button stopped only refers to page 1

What is wrong with the code below that would work in the development environment, but not on the remote host?

```
<?php
    $paged = is_front_page() ? get_query_var('page') : get_query_var('paged');
    query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged);
?>
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()): ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php if (is_singular() && get_option('thread_comments')) wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); ?>
            <div class="entry">
                <div class="SinglePost">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php
                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                echo ('<div class="HomeThumbnails">');
                                $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id() , 'full');
                                echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0] . '"width="100%"' . 'style="border-radius:20px;height:200px;" />';
                                echo ("</div>");
                            } 
                        ?>
                    </a>
                    <div class="HomePost">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="navigation">
    <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify, reduce noise and cleaned up the formatting of the code. In doing so I noticed that you're missing an `endif;` was that a copy and paste error?

Comment: Hi, thank you for editing. Yes it was a copy/paste error. Let me correct it. Im testing a theory right now about how it stopped working. Development environment was running Wordpress 4.3.1 while the remote host has Wordpress 4.4.1. Lemme see what happens if I update wordpress in the Development environment.

Comment: *What is wrong with the code* `query_posts` is complete wrong and should be avoided. It is a really really evil way to construct custom queries as it breaks many many things that happens on a page. If this is a static front page, use `WP_Query` instead

Comment: Let me look into that. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two important things here:

- Never ever use `query_posts`, it breaks all page functionalities as it breaks the main query object. It is also slow and reruns SQL queries. All in all, it is just a horrible way to run custom queries. Rather use `WP_Query` to run custom queries. [Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query) is an example of how to run a custom query with pagination.
- There is a bug in WordPress 4.4.1 (*see [trac ticket #35365](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query)*) whereby `get_query_var( 'page' )` on static front pages returns `0`. According to the linked trac ticket, it will be fixed in the next update. There are also a patch available in the link that you can use till the next release

Comment: Thanks for you input. I will definitely try out WP_Query and see what I can do with the version of Wordpress. Cheers.

Comment: My pleasure, hope you get this sorted soon. Enjoy ;-)

Comment: It was the WordPress version. I downgraded back to 4.3.1 and pagination worked again. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: My pleasure, be sure to check when the next upgrade is available for WordPress and check if the bug is fixed. Fingers crossed